# python - Get EVERY div class and div id from website

Tags: python, lxml

So there were some attempts, but i cannot find a way to get the name and content of every

- div class
- div id

Im using lxml and beautysoup in my project, but i simply cant seem to find a way to find div's that are unknown to me.
Can someone show me a method or any tips how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your best attempt at this so far.

Comment: We can't really offer you any help without details see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `find_all` method to find all tags of a certain type, then look at their attributes via ther `attrs` dict, e.g.:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for div in soup.find_all('div'):
  print(div.attrs)
```

Comment: hey sorry, wasnt able to reply.
that was my first try, and it didnt work because i made messed up the find_all parameters :( But after working that out i got it, you get the answer mark though, thank you for contributing